# Intercepting mail sent with the Pony gem, in a development environment

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, email, pony

I'm using the Pony gem for ruby on rails, and am wondering if there's a way to intercept mail in the development and staging environments (any non-production environment) and send it to a controlled address, like you can do with ActionMailer.

I know with ActionMailer you just can just use an interceptor...

Answer (score 2):

I personally use [mailcatcher](http://mailcatcher.me/) as an interceptor (I'm not sure if I'm using "interceptor" to mean the same thing you are though). Then you just need to set the default Pony.options :via_options to smtp://127.0.0.1:1025 and the mail will get sent to mailcatcher.

Answer (score 0):

Just patch the mail method in the Pony object for your environment. Something like this...

```
class Pony
  alias_method :original_mail, :mail

  def mail(args)
    args[:to] = 'intercept@example.com'
    original_mail(args)
  end
end
```

Comment: I can see how, adding some conditions based on Rails.env, this could do just what I want!  I'll give it a shot.